# Create a shared mailbox with EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

How can I connect to an exchange server and create a shared mailbox. I can not find a way to do it with AWS Managed API. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the way to do it and this is the solution if someone need it (Executing cmdlets from console application):

```
public class Service
{
    public static ExchangeService GetExchangeService(string username, string password, string ExchangeUrl)
    {
        var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

        //WebService Uri
        try
        {
            exchangeService.Url = new Uri(ExchangeUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("WebService Uri:" + ex));
        }

        //Credentials
        try
        {
            exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Credentials:" + ex));
        }
        return exchangeService;
    }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = null;
        service = Service.GetExchangeService("email@myexchangedomain.com", "mypassword", "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

      var emailCreateCommand = CreateEmailCommand("name", "displayName", "alias");
      var res2 = ExecuteCommand(emailCreateCommand);

     }


private static Command CreateEmailCommand(string name, string displayName, string alias)
    {
        Command myCommand = new Command("New-MailBox");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Shared", true);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", name);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("DisplayName", displayName);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Alias", alias);

        return myCommand;
    }



public static Collection<PSObject> ExecuteCommand(Command command)
    {
        string pass = "mypassword";
        System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();

        foreach (char c in pass.ToCharArray())
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        PSCredential newCred = new PSCredential("email@myexchangedomain.com", securePassword);


        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
            new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID"),
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
            newCred);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

        Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        myRunSpace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

        pipeLine.Commands.Add(command);
        Collection<PSObject> result = pipeLine.Invoke();
        myRunSpace.Close();
        return result;
    }
```